Are objects created with new guaranteed to stay in the same memory location? If so, does new place things to minimize cache misses & fragmentation?
Say for example I create a vector with new like this:
std::vector<int>* pointer_to_vector = new std::vector<int>{2, 4, 6, -1};
Will pointer_to_vector remain valid (not dangling) for the rest of the program as long as I don't call delete on the vector? In other words, will the object ever move in memory by itself?
I know the contents of the vector can move in memory but I'm interested in the vector object itself.
And if objects created with new don't move in memory by themselves, and you scale up a program to create lots of them, does new place them close together to minimize cache misses and memory fragmentation, or could they be scattered around distantly?
I am also aware that you can use placement new if you want to control exactly where the object is created in memory but I'm wondering how new handles this automatically.

Yes, the vector object will remain valid for the rest of the program and not move in memory by itself.  Assuming you have a valid program (not ill-formed, no undefined behavior).

"does new place them close together to minimize cache misses" Quality of Implementation.

[Pro Tip] Never new a vector.  A vector is small, most likely 24 bytes total.  The data held by the vector is already dynamically allocated by the vector, well specifically the allocator, so there is no reason to dynamically allocate the vector itself.

All objects are guaranteed to stay — during their entire lifetime — in their initial location (storage more precisely). C++ does not support any moving of objects in memory.

new typically uses malloc to allocate memory. malloc generally keeps things close together, but it also refuses memory that's been freed, which may be far away from the most recent allocation.

@NathanOliver I saw an example where maintaining 4-byte alignment in various classes was critical (bloating them to 8 bytes & doubling memory was not allowed). There was a wrapper class around vectors that created them with new and split the pointer into two unsigned ints then bit-joined them as needed to access the vector. They used new so the vector wouldn't end up in the wrapper and cause 8 byte alignment. That's where I became curious if the vector's address could change and break the pointer. Not sure if that's a good design but this question is meant for any object not just vectors.

"I am also aware that you can use placement new if you want to control exactly where the object is created in memory but I'm wondering how new handles this automatically." — new expression simply allocates memory with operator new, and then creates an object in this memory by placement new.

@greenlagoon -- that vector wrapper sounds like a horrible idea. std::vector can be created with a custom allocator that can do all of that manipulation.

@PeteBecker I read the source for std::vector and it has one member called _Mypair but its template instantiation looks non-trivial:  _Compressed_pair<_Rebind_alloc_t<_Alloc, _Ty>, _Vector_val<conditional_t<_Is_simple_alloc_v<_Alty>, _Simple_types<_Ty>,_Vec_iter_types<_Ty, size_type, difference_type, pointer, const_pointer>>>> _Mypair; How would you begin writing a custom allocator that can store the pointer as two unsigned ints and bit-join them as needed, so that _Mypair and the vector object have 4-byte alignment? Or does an allocator like this already exist?

@greenlagoon -- you don't store the pointer as two unsigned ints and bit-join them as needed; that's the horrible part of it. You write an allocator that handles alignment and object access. Read the specification for std::allocator.

@PeteBecker Thanks. Do you know if there's already an allocator available that can make std::vector a 4-byte aligned object (to avoid re-inventing the wheel)? It doesn't need to behave any differently than the default allocator other than respecting 4-byte alignment.

@greenlagoon -- I don't know of such a thing.

@PeteBecker It might be a useful standard feature to add. Any program that doesn't care about double precision and has objects that contain both contiguous values and dynamic memory could benefit (maybe cut memory requirements in half). Games are a good example of this: character objects with stats and a vector for an item inventory. You could go crazy with this idea and support 2-byte aligned vector objects to work with with bfloat16 & short ints. The horrible solution of bit-splitting pointers enables all of these things but costs an extra pointer jump & bit operations (far from ideal).


Are objects created with new guaranteed to stay in the same memory location?

Yes.
Or more specifically, a pointer like your pointer_to_vector identifies the memory location.  And for the lifetime of the object pointed to, that memory location will never become incorrect.

does new place them close together to minimize cache misses and memory fragmentation, or could they be scattered around distantly?

The C++ language makes no guarantee about the locality of multiple calls to new.  This behavior is typically decided by a particular operating system, not a language.
However, common implementations of new typically guarantee that there will always be "some space" between the memory provided by successive calls to new.
If you want several objects to be close together for cache purposes, you should make a single call to new that allocates all of those objects.

It's not just the OS that determines locality; it's also (and primarily) the implementation of malloc (which, formally, doesn't have to be the allocation function that new uses by default, but in practice it always is). malloc typically asks the OS for a large block of memory, and sub-allocates from that block until it's used up, and then it asks the OS for more.

@Drew I value your good intentions, but the addition of overloading new is probably adding confusion.

You're a straight shooter, @PepijnKramer.  I'll take you advice.

@DrewDormann I always need to remind myself to keep thing simple too :) And the straight shooting... maybe did too many code and design reviews (it is never intended to be personal)
